# How to insert an equation into a Word 2010 document inline via an escape sequence?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, equation-editor

I would like to be able to insert an equation into a word 2010 document **without** having to Click Insert -> Equation from the ribbon.
As an example:

```
the equation of a line is:
\eq(y=mx+b)
where m is the slope and b is the y-intercept. (and so on)
```

where \eq is my made up escape sequence. Is there such an escape sequence to get the equation caption? or am I out of luck? Google has not proved useful so far.

Comment: Does it have to be an escape sequence because you are running some parsing code over your document or could you just a shortcut key to get equations to insert?
[ALT] + [=]  enters you into Equation Mode and will also make a selection into an equation.

Comment: I was hoping an escape existed as it seemed like a quick way to both type it out without having to do clicking, and later on using it to programmatically pass a string from c# that turns into an equation. I have looked at the conventional method for adding an equation programmatically, and this seemed like a too good to be true idea. :x

Answer (score 0):

You could write some VB script that could scan over an entire document for these escape sequences, yes.  I couldn't tell you the exact implementation though.  However, I would suggest using opener and closers instead of an escape sequence as it may be easier to tell when the equation begins and when the equation ends.   *some equation here*

Answer (score 0):

### Solution A

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>

### Solution B

Use AutoCorrect Options:

- insert an empty equation
- mark it
- go to "File -> Options -> Proofing -> AutoCorrect Options ..."
- In the section "Replace text as you type" you will find your marked empty equation filled into the "With" field (do not modify it!)
- you insert your escape sequence into "replace", click "Add" and "OK"

See https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/word-2007-setting-up-seq-fields-for-numbering-pt-1/ for a pictured tutorial (in the middle of the article).